# как переключить раскладку в tty?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

В последнее время начал работать исключительно через терминал, причем не эмуляцию терминала из под иксов, а просто терминал без графики.
В графическом режиме между раскладками переключаюсь сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl+Z`, но в `tty` эта комбинация не работает.
В файле `/etc/default/keyboard` согласно инструкциям найденным в сети дописал `grp:alt_shift_toogle` - сочетание клавиш `Alt+Shift` после этого так и не стало работать, ни в графическом режиме, ни в `tty`. По умолчанию стоит английский язык, на русский переключиться так и не получается, хотя сама кириллица нормально отображается

Как мне настроить переключение между языками в `tty`.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Keyboard_configuration_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: и контрол+Я сочетание переводит процесс в фон. лучше не использовать его чтоб не ломать нормальное поведение

Comment: Всю инструкцию исколесил уже, не работает

Comment: 60% команд из инструкции не работают, а файлы из нее по факту там не лежат - может те кто пользуются арчем и оценят но для ubuntu она абсолютно бесполезная

Comment: В дебиане - man keyboard, man setupcon. Возможно, и в убунте так же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы переключаться между языками стандартными для многих сочетаниями клавиш (типа `Alt+Shift` и `Ctrl+Shift`) нужен оконный менеджер. Именно он обрабатывает подобные сочетания клавиш. Чистый же `tty` может переключать языки только командой `loadkeys` в связке с кратким обозначением языка(`ru`, `en`, `de` и т. д.). Приведенной выше командой лучше пользоваться вводя сперва `loadkeys en` (при необходимости `sudo`), чтобы можно было переключиться обратно на английский язык. Если этого не сделать и сразу переключиться на допустим `loadkeys ru` - то в лучшем случае вам останется только переключиться на другой `tty` и продолжить свою работу оттуда, так как обратно на английский перейти уже не выйдет.

Comment: По ссылке, что скинул @eri, написано, что это для временной конфигурации, а не единственный возможный вариант. У меня всё работает для постоянной конфигурации, если делать, как там написано. Трудно поверить, что нет способов сделать это для постоянной конфигурации в вашем дистрибутиве. Лучше укажите конкретные команды, которые вы выполняете, наблюдаемое поведение, логи и ошибки, чтобы можно было отладить.

Comment: Эта информация - можно сказать больше для новичков, не сильно сложная и в то же время рабочая (так сказать с пометкой "на первое время сойдет", особенно для тех кто по умолчанию устанавливал Ubuntu с русской раскладкой и теперь базовые папки на русском языке и как это было у меня с отвалившимся X сервером. Вопрос не из популярных так что информация скорее как закладка для себя, а также если найду более действенный и удобный способ - обязательно опишу его здесь. Так чтобы даже такие новички как я поняли как это работает и смогли решить проблему не занимаясь поиском работающих ответов сутками)))

Comment: P.S. просто когда я искал решение пролемы в интернете, мне почти все время попадались ответы не на тему как переключить раскладку при настроенной кириллице, а как настроить отображение кириллицы в tty. И таких ответов не по теме 95%. Может у кого то по другому было - поделитесь в комментариях найденными решениями - но у меня на тот момент круглого новичка поиск решения занял около недели.